# if else in a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, if-statement

I want to create a variable region based on a series of similar variables zipid1 to zipid26. My current code is like this:

```
dat$region <- with(dat, ifelse(zipid1 == 1, 1, 
                                         ifelse(zipid2 == 1, 2, 
                                                ifelse(zipid3 == 1, 3,
                                                       ifelse(zipid4 == 1, 4,
                                                              5)))))
```

How can I write a loop to avoid typing from zipid1 to zipid26? Thanks!

Comment: You can avoid a lot more if you keep your data long (i.e., one zip column adjacent to 1 - 26 id indicators).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We subset the 'zipid' columns, create a logical matrix by comparing with 1 (`== 1`), get the column index of the `TRUE` value with `max.col` (assuming there is only a single 1 per each row and assign it to create 'region'

```
dat$region <- max.col(dat[paste0("zipid", 1:26)] == 1, "first")
```

Using a small reproducible example

```
max.col(dat[paste0("zipid", 1:5)] == 1, "first")
```

#### data

```
dat <- data.frame(id = 1:5, zipid1 = c(1, 3, 2, 4, 5), 
  zipid2 = c(2, 1, 3, 5, 4), zipid3 = c(3, 2, 1, 5, 4),
  zipid4 = c(4, 3, 6, 2, 1), zipid5 = c(5, 3, 8, 1, 4))
```